# docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 -i --isolation=hyperv resulting in errors. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm running a valid, licensed copy of Windows 11 Pro.

```
> docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.13
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Thu Mar 10 14:13:04 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.6.1 (76265)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.13
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       906f57f
  Built:            Thu Mar 10 14:08:21 2022
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

According to Docker's [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11-21H2), using `--isolation=hyperv` should make most versions of windows images compatible:

[image]

So it seems like compatibility shouldn't be an issue with hyper-v.

Well, when I run:

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 -i --isolation=hyperv
```

I get the error:

```
docker : Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022' locally
At line:1 char:1
+ docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 -i --isolati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to find ...sc2022' locally:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
ltsc2022: Pulling from windows/servercore
8f616e6e9eec: Pulling fs layer
037d5740b404: Pulling fs layer
037d5740b404: Verifying Checksum
037d5740b404: Download complete
8f616e6e9eec: Verifying Checksum
8f616e6e9eec: Download complete
8f616e6e9eec: Pull complete
037d5740b404: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:343f8c95ec604913c74597f6d541e388f83bc0ce373ee8ea5bb26d268879f338
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
docker: Error response from daemon: container 597ea2d8b5564b2a8771980c3c809b6e059d00d8bc831e97b3cf14a071820aed encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find 
the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF61BE0EFBD: (caller: 00007FF61BDB4E97) Exception(2) tid(3c8) 80070002 The system cannot find the 
file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess] 
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

This is after I've tried many different images, with and without hyper-v, restarted my PC, and reset Docker to factory default settings.

Removing `--isolation=hyperv` results in precisely the same error.

What could be going on here?

Comment: Do you have all the required Windows features enabled?

Comment: @DanielB I believe so. Before today I was able to run a Windows nanoserver container. Granted, it was an image I pulled months ago and I don't recall the version. I haven't changed any BIOS settings. What features would I need to verify other than hyper-v?

Comment: Hyper-V is apparently enough. // Another possibility occurred to me: The base image may not specify a command to run and you don’t either.

Comment: @DanielB I tried it with no success. I've also now tried reinstalling Docker. Anyhow the documentation states: The default entrypoint is for this image is Cmd.exe. To run the image:

`docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2`.

Comment: @DanielB However, I just noticed, if I run the *image* straight from the CLI, it works.... How odd

Comment: I figured out the issue. All of this testing has been from a PowerShell ISE terminal. And that's creating the issue somehow. From any other terminal, it actually works.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1715429/587488

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. All of this testing has been from a PowerShell ISE terminal. And that's creating the issue somehow. From any other terminal, it actually works.

I've reported this as a bug to the Docker CLI GitHub repo.

Edit: **I was wrong.** Yes the error stopped happening, but the result is still dead containers, from any PowerShell terminal. I've created an issue: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3548

Edit 2: Ahhhh. Figured it out. One decidedly ignored bug (PowerShell ISE fails with error handling that doesn't shed any light on the actual problem, that's the issue), and a documentation inconsistency. That's what all this comes down to. If I run the command [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container#run-a-windows-container) (with -it) it runs fine. I was running the command `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:2022` [documented here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver). It says:

[image]

> The default entry-point is for this image is Cmd.exe. To run the image:
>
> `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:2022`

I would argue this documentation is just plain wrong, or at the very least misleading.

So first I was running it from the wrong place, and then I was running the wrong command, which the Docker page for that image says to use.

Comment: Microsoft [explicitly mentions this limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container#run-a-windows-container). Docker is not to blame here.

Comment: @DanielB "appears to hang", sounds more like a bug they didn't feel like fixing than something a user should know. With all the many docker docs out there,  most people are not going to notice that little (*btw no PS ISE*) mention on one page. They should at least catch this and produce a helpful error message.

Comment: @DanielB See edit :/

Comment: Ok fixed. `-it` (and not using ISE) works.

Answer (score 1):

These arguments are being passed in the wrong order:

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 -i --isolation=hyperv
```

You need to pass the options to `docker run` before the image name. E.g.

```
docker run -i --isolation=hyperv mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
```