# Am I misusing the --name argument for Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

This works:
`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 --isolation=hyperv`

I get a CLI for the container, everything is good.

This doesn't work:
`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 --isolation=hyperv --name=workstation_1`

When I add the `--name=workstation_1` argument, which according to `docker run --help` is a valid argument:

[image]

I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 1118d316b0700307943bec10392b39266b79db08350311618fb5bfc247e2fa8d encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6EBB1A40B: (caller: 00007FF6EBAD5C8B) Exception(1) tid(398) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

Am I misusing the --name argument? How else should I name my container? I'm scripting this, so need a (practical) way to do it without human intervention.

I can list containers, assume the first one in the list is the new one, and use `docker rename`, but using that approach for an automated build pipeline seems undesirable for obvious reasons.

As an alternative, I tried:

```
docker create mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 --name=workstation_1
```

and

```
docker create mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 --name="workstation_1"
```

Since `docker create --help` indicates this is also a valid argument:

[image]

And this doesn't fail, but it also doesn't name the container.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I also tried `--name string` (but Docker documentation examples, they show other `--flagname` arguments assigned via `=`) such as `--isolation=hyperv` [demonstrated here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container#create-container)

Answer (score 2):

Note the first part of the help message:

```
$ docker run --help

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Everything after the image name is overriding the default command and args to that command. So

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 --isolation=hyperv --name=workstation_1
```

Will run launch a container with the `-it` options, in a container based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2` image, running the command `--isolation=hyperv --name=workstation_1`. To fix, put these options before the image name:

```
docker run -it --isolation=hyperv --name=workstation_1 mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
```